# How does Form layout exactly work?

Tags: sapui5

I have a simple form, that looks as following:

[image]

the code:

```
<VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
    <sf:SimpleForm id="PayerSel" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanXL="1" labelSpanL="1" labelSpanM="1" labelSpanS="12"
        adjustLabelSpan="false" emptySpanXL="5" emptySpanL="5" emptySpanM="5" emptySpanS="0" columnsXL="1" columnsL="1" columnsM="1"
        singleContainerFullSize="false">
        <sf:content>
            <Label text="Payers"></Label>
            <Input id="payerFrom" placeholder="From" required="true"/>
            <Input id="payerTo" placeholder="Until" required="true"/>
        </sf:content>
    </sf:SimpleForm>
</VBox>
```

The questions are:

- How to configure that both inputs have same length?
- When I change `columnsL="1"` to `columnsL="4"`, why the input is
  getting smaller? I give more space and expect it to be wider, because I give to space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the API:

> - A new Title or Toolbar starts a new group (FormContainer) in the form.
> - A new Label starts a new row (FormElement) in the form.
> - All other controls will be assigned to the row (FormElement) that started with the last label.

The code exmple uses 1 group with 1 row.

`columns<size>` The layout will be divided into column columns in  size

Without playing with spans here is an example for different columns, each column with 1 row and Label width + Input width + Input width = 2 + 5 + 5 in all size: ([Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pKqCv7lUtkeZ40k3DjQK?p=preview) - try to resize the browser window and examine the result)

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
        xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
        <f:SimpleForm id="PayerSel" editable="true"
                layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                labelSpanXL="0"
                labelSpanL="0"
                labelSpanM="0"
                labelSpanS="0"
                columnsL="1">
            <f:content>
                <Label text="Payers">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="payerFrom" placeholder="From" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Input id="payerTo" placeholder="Until" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
        <f:SimpleForm id="PayerSel2" editable="true"
                layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                labelSpanXL="0"
                labelSpanL="0"
                labelSpanM="0"
                labelSpanS="0"
                columnsL="2"
                columnsM="2">
            <f:content>
                <core:Title text="group1"/>
                <Label text="Payers">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="payerFrom2" placeholder="From" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Input id="payerTo2" placeholder="Until" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <core:Title text="group2"/>
                <Label text="Payers">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="payerFrom3" placeholder="From" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Input id="payerTo3" placeholder="Until" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
        <f:SimpleForm id="PayerSel3" editable="true"
                layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
                labelSpanXL="0"
                labelSpanL="0"
                labelSpanM="0"
                labelSpanS="0"
                columnsL="3"
                columnsM="3">
            <f:content>
                <core:Title text="group1"/>
                <Label text="Payers">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="payerFrom32" placeholder="From" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Input id="payerTo32" placeholder="Until" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <core:Title text="group2"/>
                <Label text="Payers">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="payerFrom33" placeholder="From" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Input id="payerTo33" placeholder="Until" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <core:Title text="group3"/>
                <Label text="Payers">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Label>
                <Input id="payerFrom34" placeholder="From" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
                <Input id="payerTo34" placeholder="Until" required="true">
                    <layoutData>
                        <l:GridData span="L5 M5 S5"/>
                    </layoutData>
                </Input>
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
    </VBox>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Comment: What does `columnsL="1"` mean, it will show only one column on the large screen?

Comment: Yes, it means: "Form columns for large size" no to confuse with grid column. The form will be divided / will contain 1 *form column* in large size, means 1 horizontal block per form row. So the label and the two input will be in one row, full form width - in large size the ratio will be 2:5:5 (L2 L5 L5 in GridData) Check it here: (in large size) [https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cjcjkywyu00063c64n7qg2vlf/](https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cjcjkywyu00063c64n7qg2vlf/) the first row has columnsL="1" the second has two groups with columnsL="2" and the last three groups with columnsL="3"

Answer (score 0):

When you change columnsL="1" to columnsL="4", the input is getting smaller because "columnsL" attribute is stands for "The number of columns for large size". That means if you want 4 columns in your page and don't provide any width, every columns has width 25% of the parent component's width. Obviously they will be smaller than 1 column.

link : [more info](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm/methods/setColumnsL)

Edit: You're using ResponsiveGridLayout in your simpleForm. If you want to your inputs have same width then just use "layoutdata".

```
<Input id="payerFrom" placeholder="From" required="true">
   <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L4 M6 S12"/> //for example
   </layoutData>
</>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your response.
The entire screen is divided into 12 equal blocks and what is the ratio of:
`<sf:SimpleForm id="PayerSel" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanXL="1" labelSpanL="1" labelSpanM="1" labelSpanS="12"

 adjustLabelSpan="false" emptySpanXL="5" emptySpanL="5" emptySpanM="5" emptySpanS="0" columnsXL="1" columnsL="1" columnsM="1"

 singleContainerFullSize="false">

` it that mean `1:1:5`? If yes it does not satisfy the quantity of 12 grid.

Comment: ratio is 12 unless you change it :)
simply: given that we have a large screen.
"emptySpanL=5" : empty spans take 5 blocks.
"labelSpanL=1" : labels  take 1 block.
"columnsL=1" : here you want 1 column to take "6" blocks. (you can see it is all that we have after all)

you want to change it after that? look at my edit in the answer. There we want that input take 4 blocks. And what we have now? 2 blocks. you can add another input there if you want.